# Can't read Gatt characteristic (gatt error 15)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm trying to read a characteristic right after gatt connected and services discovered successfully. But receives error 15 (0x0f, GATT_INSUFFICIENT_ENCRYPTION) and then 137 (0x0089) in `onCharacteristicRead` gatt callback. After this error gatt disconnecting immediately.

My device is Samsung S4, 4.4.2.

Comment: Are you able to read that characteristic from this peripheral successfully using some other BLE-enabled system?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I can read it successfully on samsung s3 (I9300)

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know both errors, "GATT_INSUFFICIENT_ENCRYPTION" and "GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION" gets occurred when you try to do a GATT operation that requires encryption. This means that you need to pair with the remote BLE device before trying to do any GATT operations, for example reading a characteristic or writing to a characteristic etc.

Have a look at the following [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645519/android-how-can-i-make-ble-device-to-paired-device-bonded/24740344#24740344) to see the different ways to pair with a BLE device.