# Android Things and Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, android-things

As far as I read about the dev boards, every SoC is capable to use Bluetooth.

I didn't tested it yet, but can I use Android Things with a Bluetooth connection? My question is, how can I enable Bluetooth without an input device? If I want to enable Bluetooth on my phone (with code), I had to confirm it, but this can't be possible on Android Things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** Since the release of Android Things developer preview 3, Bluetooth and BLE are now available.

**Old Answer**

No. You can not use Bluetooth with the current version of AndroidThings (developer preview 1).

It is said in the *known issues* part of the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html) that Bluetooth is currently disabled (and so is USB).

It is supposed to be included at some point, but at the moment if you try to get a *BluetoothAdapter* it does return **null**.

Answer (score 1):

Android Things will use the latest version of Bluetooth called Bluetooth Low Energy and the only similarity between the two is that they have Bluetooth in the name!

> Can I use Android Things with a Bluetooth connection?

Yes, well a Bluetooth Low Energy connection

https://www.link-labs.com/bluetooth-vs-bluetooth-low-energy/

> In summary, Bluetooth and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) are used for very different purposes. Bluetooth can handle a lot of data, but consumes battery life quickly and costs a lot more. BLE is used for applications that do not need to exchange large amounts of data, and can therefore run on battery power for years at a cheaper cost. It all depends on what you’re trying to accomplish.

Everything you need to know about BLE is written here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

> how can I enable Bluetooth without an input device?

You do not pair BLE devices like you used to with the older Bluetooth (but you can use Bonding). Check this out:

`Android Bluetooth Low Energy Pairing`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20093695/413127

But as stated by @shalafi Android Things doesn't currently support Bluetooth

Comment: Is Bluetooth always enabled, because on a phone I can disable it.